# Google home actions.fulfillment.devices not getting enabled

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I am using google smarthome actions for IOT... I updated my action url and account linking details. When i am trying to enable the Test in simulator to deploy my TestAPP to cloud, it fails and it gets me an error "GoogleFulfillment 'actions.fulfillment.devices' is not supported" and the linked app not update old URL. This worked a few days ago. Any changes from google side or anybody has any clue ?

Comment: It seems to really be an internal problem with Google. Follow the link in more detail:
https://community.home-assistant.io/t/google-assistant-trouble-shooting/99223/42

Answer (score 1):

There is a manual workaround. Thanks for Google Assistatant forum:

Steps:
1 - Download the gactions cli at https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli

2 - Authenticate with any command:

```
./gactions list --project [YOUT_PROJECT_ID]
```

3 - Download the json representation of your action:

```
./gactions get --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] --version draft > action.json
```

4 - Edit the json. Extract the only object from its array, remove the nested “googleFulfillments” object:

```
"googleFulfillments": [
    {
      "endpoint": {
        "baseUrl": "[URL]"
      },
      "name": "actions.fulfillment.devices"
    }
  ],
```

5 - Delete the brackets "[ ]" on the top and end of file. Only one language can be activated at a time. Delete all data from the action.json file unnecessary. The file looks like this, with its parameters:

```
{
    "accountLinking": {
        "accessTokenUrl": "xxxx",
        "assertionTypes": [
            "ID_TOKEN"
        ],
        "authenticationUrl": "xxx",
        "clientId": "xxx",
        "clientSecret": "xxxx",
        "grantType": "AUTH_CODE"
    },
    "actions": [
        {
            "description": "Smart home action for project xxxxxxx",
            "fulfillment": {
                "conversationName": "AoGSmartHomeConversation_xxxxxx"
            },
            "name": "actions.devices"
        }
    ],
    "conversations": {
        "AoGSmartHomeConversation_xxxxxxxx": {
            "name": "",
            "url": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "locale": "en",
    "manifest": {
        "category": "xxx",
        "companyName": "xxx",
        "contactEmail": "xxx",
        "displayName": "xxx",
        "largeLandscapeLogoUrl": "xxxxxx",
        "longDescription": "xxxx",
        "privacyUrl": "xxx",
        "shortDescription": "xxxx",
        "smallSquareLogoUrl": "xxxx",
        "termsOfServiceUrl": "xxxxx",
        "testingInstructions": "xxxxx"
    }
}
```

6 - If you have updated the URL of fulfillment, authentication or token, go to Google Actions Console and update his entry on there;

7 - Push your fixed action into test:

```
./gactions test --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] --action_package ./action.json
```

This replaces the step " Click Simulator under TEST" in the google assistant manual setup. It worked for me!

More help here: https://community.home-assistant.io/t/google-assistant-trouble-shooting/99223/142